# How to color polygons based on different value ranges and null values in mapbox-gl-js?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I'm trying to color polygons based on different value ranges. However, null values display as black. I'm not sure what would be the expression to explicitly say "use white colors for null values".

```
 paint: {
          "fill-color": [
  "step",
  ["get", "value"],
  "#f1eef6",
  100,
  "#bdc9e1",
  200,
  "#74a9cf",
  300,
  "#2b8cbe",
  400,
  "#045a8d"
],
  "fill-opacity": 1
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

I think I figured it out:

```
 "fill-color": [
  "case",
  ["==", ["get", "value"], null],
  "white",
  ["step", ["get", "value"], "#deebf7", 25, "#9ecae1", 50, "#3182bd"]
];
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is to use `["match"]` and set white as the default colour. Which also catches any other values you may not have thought of.

```
 "fill-color": [
  "match",
  ["get", "value"],
  "#f1eef6",
  100,
  "#bdc9e1",
  200,
  "#74a9cf",
  300,
  "#2b8cbe",
  400,
  "#045a8d",
  "white"
],
```

Comment: It gives "Expected an even number of arguments" error. Doesn't "match" look for exact match? I'm trying to color the values between 0-100, 100-200, 200-300, 300-400 and >=400

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Steve! It helped me to figure it out.